# Detached Entity passed to persist error

Tags: jpa, many-to-one

I have a `@ManyToOne` relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Produkt implements Serializable { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String ausstattung;

    @Basic
    private String hersteller;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @Basic
    private Boolean veraltet;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProduktArt.class, cascade= CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private ProduktArt typ;

    @Basic
    private String ausstattungsTyp;

    // ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class ProduktArt implements Serializable { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @Basic
    private Boolean sichtbarFuerKunde;

    // ...
}
```

Which is persisted as below:

```
getEntityManager().persist(produkt);
```

It always throws this exception:

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: ProduktArt

When I remove `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST`:

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Solved by adding "@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)" instead of "@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)"